# Listeing to a port?

Tags: authentication, xmpp, tcp-port

I am wondering if its possible to to open a port listen for a connection, if a connection is made authenticate it, and if it passes the authentication then an event is fired? Is it maybe possible to do this with XMPP?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick search suggested [Twisted Words](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedWords) might be a good candidate.  [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) is an event-driven Python networking library, and Twisted Words is their chat component.